# Using a decorator to type check an instance attribute

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I'm trying to use a decorator to type check an instance attribute. Below is my current code (which still raises an error).

Is this something that can be done in Python? If so, how?

```py
import functools
from typing import Optional


def guarantee(func):
  @functools.wraps(func)
  def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.maybe_none is None:
      raise ValueError
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper


class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.maybe_none: Optional[str] = None

  def set(self, value: str):
    self.maybe_none = value

  @guarantee
  def get(self) -> str:
    return self.maybe_none # Incompatible return value type
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem here? The code raises an error when the value is `None`, and it returns the value otherwise. How is this different than the behavior you want?

Comment: You seem to be confusing static typing with runtime behavior. `mypy` should  and does flag the attempt to return a value of type `Optional[str]` in a function that claims to return a value of type `str`. But the decorator doesn't do anything until you actually *call* the method, at which point it can succeed or fail based on the *actual* value of `self.maybe_none` (which may well be a `str`).

Comment: an annoying thing you could do to appease the typechecker is to `return str(self.maybe_none)`, since that will make it very explicit it is a string

Comment: @chepner I think that makes sense, but then why does adding the 'None check' directly before the return (in the method that is) work?

Comment: @MichaelRuth this question is about the static type checker.

Comment: `mypy` can perform type narrowing in certain (hard-coded) situations. If you put the check in `get` itself, `mypy` can use the information that `return self.maybe_none` can only be *reached* if `self.maybe_none` is not `None` to infer a compatible type for the expression. But putting the check in a decorator is too far removed from what `mypy` is written to look for.

Comment: Type-narrowing involves a certain amount of "simulation", predicting what code will do when executed rather than relying on explicit type hints. While `mypy` could certainly expand on how much simulation it does, every bit will slow `mypy` down that much more. At some point, there's a trade-off between inferring types and being able to type-check code quickly.

Comment: You can use `return cast(str, self.maybe_none)` if you, as the programmer, are confident that the decorator does, in fact, ensure that only `str`-valued expressions will be returned at runtime. But beware: `cast`, despite the name, does not actually do anything to provide a `str` value; it effectively just turns off type-checking at this point and says to the type checker "Yes, the expression is a `str`". The type checker would be just as happy with `return cast(str, None)`, trusting you that `None` is, in fact, a value of type `str`.

Comment: I decided to use an `@property` for `maybe_none` that does the check.